# How to check if a row does not exist in another column?

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

dict_1 = {'Col1':[1,1,1,1,2,4,5,6,7],'Col2':[3,3,3,3,2,4,5,6,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
filt = df.apply(lambda x: x['Col2'] not in df['Col1'],axis = 1)
print(filt)
```

That's is what I tried the expected output is:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    False 
5    False 
6    False 
7    False 
8    False
```

The given result is

```
0    False 
1    False 
2    False 
3    False 
4    False 
5    False 
6    False 
7    False 
8    False
```

It is only giving false no matter what I do, and I am not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
filt = ~df.Col2.isin(df.Col1.unique())
```

OUTPUT:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
```

Comment: What would I do if there is a space in the column name, like Col 1 instead of Col2

Answer (score 0):

In general, using df.COLUMN notation has the drawback you mention in that it is not obvious how to reference them.

```py
~df["Col2"].isin(df["Col1"].unique())
```

Remember that when using square brackets instead of .dot notation, single square brackets returns a Series, while double-square brackets return a DataFrame.

```py
isinstance(df["Col2"], pandas.Series)
```

OUTPUT:

```py
True
```

Versus

```py
isinstance(df[["Col2"]], pandas.DataFrame)
```

OUTPUT:

```py
True
```